# Can I generate CMake files from Netbeans IDE?

Tags: netbeans, makefile, cmake

I have a project that has been written in Netbeans 8.0 and the Makefile is generated by Netbeans. My client would like CMake files instead of the Netbeans Makefiles. Is there a way to do this from Netbeans?

I have looked at questions and answers on generating Netbeans projects from Cmakelists, but not the other way around.

Please note, if it was just one project, I'd just use CMake and recreate the projects, but there are about 40 projects which are interdependent and have tests, etc. all set up in Netbeans.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, there's no save way to convert makefiles (in general) to cmake yet.

> Please note, if it was just one project, I'd just use CMake and recreate the projects, but there are about 40 projects which are interdependent and have tests, etc. all set up in Netbeans.

This is a realy unhappy situation. You could write a parser your own, but this may not be adequate in many cases.

So i think you need some hand work. But there are some tipps which make live easier:

- Cmake files can be used in a generic manner, one file may work for several projects
- Use sub-cmakelists where possible
- Dependencies can be solved with modules / packages
- Lots of makefile stuff can be feed directly into cmake calls
- Don't add each source file by hand, use `file()` do search (and where necessary filter) source files
- CMake allows different targes (as makefiles do)

Comment: Thanks Ollo. I spoke to my client and they understand the situation.